# Floodfill Scanline pixel in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, pixel, flood-fill

I am using floodFillScanline https://lodev.org/cgtutor/floodfill.html algorithm in swift but its not working as expected.

Also performance wise it looks bit slow currently I am getting

> Runtime: 0.33456450200174004s

```
func floodFillScanlineStackV3(x: Int, y: Int,
                            color_Grid: [[Int]], newColor: Int, oldColor: Int,
                            height: Int, width: Int) -> [[Int]] {
    var colorGrid = color_Grid
    
    assert(x < width, "p.x \(x) out of range, must be < \(width)")
    assert(y < height, "p.y \(y) out of range, must be < \(height)")
    
    if oldColor == newColor { return [] }
    
    var stack : [(Int, Int)] = [(x, y)] // 0 is X, 1 is Y
    
    while let pp = stack.popLast() {
        
        var x1 = pp.0
        
        while(x1 >= 0 && colorGrid[pp.1][x1] == oldColor) {
            x1 -= 1
        }
        
        x1 += 1
        
        var spanAbove = false
        var spanBelow = false
        
        while(x1 < width && compareColor(oldColor, colorGrid[pp.1][pp.0])) {
            colorGrid[x1][pp.1] = newColor
            
            let north = (x1, pp.1-1)
            let south = (x1, pp.1+1)
            
            if spanAbove == false && pp.1 > 0 &&  compareColor(colorGrid[x1][pp.1-1], oldColor) {
                stack.append(north)
                spanAbove = true
            } else if spanAbove && pp.1 > 0 && !compareColor(colorGrid[x1][pp.1-1], oldColor) {
                spanAbove = false
            } else if spanBelow == false && pp.1 < height - 1 && compareColor(colorGrid[x1][pp.1+1], oldColor) {
                stack.append(south)
                spanBelow = true
            } else if spanBelow && pp.1 < height - 1 && compareColor(colorGrid[x1][pp.1+1], oldColor) { //!_colorIsEqual(south, pixelBuffer, rgba) {
                spanBelow = false
            }
            
            x1 += 1
        }
    }
    
    return colorGrid
}
```

Before flood fill [image]

After flood fill [image]

Comment: Start debugging and post your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have a much better chance of translating that code to Swift by keeping it closer to the original.

```
func floodFillScanlineStackV4(x: Int, y: Int,
                              color_Grid: [Int],
                              newColor: Int, oldColor: Int,
                              h: Int, w: Int) -> [Int] {
    
    var screenBuffer = color_Grid
    
    assert(x < w, "p.x \(x) out of range, must be < \(w)")
    assert(y < h, "p.y \(y) out of range, must be < \(h)")
    
    if oldColor == newColor { return [] }
    
    var x1: Int = 0
    
    var stack : [(Int, Int)] = [(x, y)] // 0 is X, 1 is Y
    
    while let pp = stack.popLast() {
        
        x1 = pp.0
        let y = pp.1
        
        while(x1 >= 0 && screenBuffer[y * w + x1] == oldColor) {
            x1 -= 1
        }
        x1 += 1
        
        var spanAbove = false
        var spanBelow = false
        
        while(x1 < w && screenBuffer[y * w + x1] == oldColor) {
            screenBuffer[y * w + x1] = newColor;
            
            if(!spanAbove && y > 0 && screenBuffer[(y - 1) * w + x1] == oldColor) {
                stack.append((x1, y - 1))
                spanAbove = true
            }
            else if(spanAbove && y > 0 && screenBuffer[(y - 1) * w + x1] != oldColor) {
                spanAbove = false
            }
            if(!spanBelow && y < h - 1 && screenBuffer[(y + 1) * w + x1] == oldColor) {
                stack.append((x1, y + 1))
                spanBelow = true
            }
            else if(spanBelow && y < h - 1 && screenBuffer[(y + 1) * w + x1] != oldColor) {
                spanBelow = false
            }
            x1 += 1
        }
    }
    
    return screenBuffer
}

func compareColor(_ v1: Int, _ v2: Int) -> Bool {
    return v1 == v2
}
```

To do that, instead of using a two-dimensional array of Int, use a one-dimensional array.

Here's some example code. Note that this is **Example Code** only, with minimal error checking, and is not intended to be considered "Production Ready":

```
class FloodVC: UIViewController {
    
    let gridWidth: Int = 12
    let gridHeight: Int = 12
    var bufLength: Int = 0
    
    let gridSpacing: CGFloat = 1
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.60, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 0.60, green: 1.00, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 0.20, green: 0.85, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 0.60, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.60, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.0),
    ]
    
    var grid: [Int] = []
    
    var newColor: Int = 2
    
    lazy var gridStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = gridSpacing
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    let colorStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.spacing = 8
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    let infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        bufLength = gridWidth * gridHeight
        
        // init array to all Zeroes
        grid = Array(repeating: 0, count: bufLength)
        
        for _ in 0..<gridHeight {
            let rs = UIStackView()
            rs.distribution = .fillEqually
            rs.spacing = gridSpacing
            for _ in 0..<gridWidth {
                let v = UILabel()
                v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
                v.textAlignment = .center
                v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                let g = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cellTap(_:)))
                v.addGestureRecognizer(g)
                rs.addArrangedSubview(v)
            }
            gridStack.addArrangedSubview(rs)
        }
        
        view.addSubview(gridStack)
        
        for i in 0..<colors.count {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.text = "\(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = colors[i]
            v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            if i == newColor {
                v.layer.borderWidth = 1
            }
            let g = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(newColorTap(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(g)
            colorStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        let shapeStack: UIStackView = {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.spacing = 8
            v.distribution = .fillEqually
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return v
        }()
        
        ["Square", "Cross", "Triangle", "Random"].forEach { str in
            let v = UIButton()
            v.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .light)
            v.setTitle(str, for: [])
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            v.layer.borderWidth = 1
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setupShape(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            shapeStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        let optionsStack: UIStackView = {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.axis = .vertical
            v.spacing = 8
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return v
        }()
        
        optionsStack.addArrangedSubview(shapeStack)
        optionsStack.addArrangedSubview(colorStack)
        
        view.addSubview(optionsStack)
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            shapeStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            shapeStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            shapeStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            gridStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            gridStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            gridStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gridStack.widthAnchor),
            gridStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            infoLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

        ])
        
        setupSquare()
    }
    
    @objc func newColorTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        guard let v = g.view as? UILabel,
              let t = v.text,
              let idx = Int(t)
        else { return }
        
        for i in 0..<colorStack.arrangedSubviews.count {
            colorStack.arrangedSubviews[i].layer.borderWidth = i == idx ? 1 : 0
        }
        
        newColor = idx
        
    }
    
    @objc func cellTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        guard let v = g.view as? UILabel,
              let t = v.text,
              let oldColor = Int(t),
              let rowStack = v.superview as? UIStackView,
              let c = rowStack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: v),
              let r = gridStack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: rowStack)
        else { return }
        

        let st = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        let newGrid = floodFillScanlineStackV4(x: c, y: r, color_Grid: grid, newColor: newColor, oldColor: oldColor, h: gridHeight, w: gridWidth)
        
        let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - st

        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.maximumFractionDigits = 8

        infoLabel.text = "Elapsed Time: " + nf.string(from: NSNumber(value: elapsed))! + " seconds"

        // if new color equals tapped cell color,
        //  newGrid will be empty
        if newGrid.count != 0 {
            grid = newGrid
            refreshGrid(grid)
        }
    }
    
    func refreshGrid(_ g: [Int]) {
        
        for i in 0..<bufLength {
            let r = i / gridWidth
            guard let rs = gridStack.arrangedSubviews[r] as? UIStackView
            else { fatalError("bad setup") }
            for c in 0..<gridWidth {
                guard let v = rs.arrangedSubviews[c] as? UILabel
                else { fatalError("bad setup") }
                let p = r * gridWidth + c
                v.text = "\(g[p])"
                v.backgroundColor = colors[g[p]]
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func floodFillScanlineStackV4(x: Int, y: Int,
                                  color_Grid: [Int],
                                  newColor: Int, oldColor: Int,
                                  h: Int, w: Int) -> [Int] {
        
        var screenBuffer = color_Grid
        
        assert(x < w, "p.x \(x) out of range, must be < \(w)")
        assert(y < h, "p.y \(y) out of range, must be < \(h)")
        
        if oldColor == newColor { return [] }
        
        var x1: Int = 0
        
        var stack : [(Int, Int)] = [(x, y)] // 0 is X, 1 is Y
        
        while let pp = stack.popLast() {
            
            x1 = pp.0
            let y = pp.1
            
            while(x1 >= 0 && screenBuffer[y * w + x1] == oldColor) {
                x1 -= 1
            }
            x1 += 1
            
            var spanAbove = false
            var spanBelow = false
            
            while(x1 < w && screenBuffer[y * w + x1] == oldColor) {
                screenBuffer[y * w + x1] = newColor;
                
                if(!spanAbove && y > 0 && screenBuffer[(y - 1) * w + x1] == oldColor) {
                    stack.append((x1, y - 1))
                    spanAbove = true
                }
                else if(spanAbove && y > 0 && screenBuffer[(y - 1) * w + x1] != oldColor) {
                    spanAbove = false
                }
                if(!spanBelow && y < h - 1 && screenBuffer[(y + 1) * w + x1] == oldColor) {
                    stack.append((x1, y + 1))
                    spanBelow = true
                }
                else if(spanBelow && y < h - 1 && screenBuffer[(y + 1) * w + x1] != oldColor) {
                    spanBelow = false
                }
                x1 += 1
            }
        }
        
        return screenBuffer
    }
    
    func compareColor(_ v1: Int, _ v2: Int) -> Bool {
        return v1 == v2
    }

    // MARK: grid setups
    @objc func setupShape(_ sender: Any?) {
        var t: String = "square"
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton {
            t = btn.currentTitle ?? "square"
        }
        switch t {
        case "Square":
            setupSquare()
            ()
        case "Cross":
            setupCross()
            ()
        case "Triangle":
            setupTriangle()
            ()
        default:
            setupRandom()
            ()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func setupSquare() {
        
        // init array to all Zeroes
        grid = Array(repeating: 0, count: bufLength)
        
        let row1: Int = 2
        let row2: Int = gridHeight - (row1 + 1)
        let col1: Int = 2
        let col2: Int = gridWidth - (col1 + 1)
        
        for r in row1...row2 {
            for c in col1...col2 {
                let p = r * gridWidth + c
                grid[p] = 1
            }
        }
        
        refreshGrid(grid)
        
    }
    
    @objc func setupCross() {
        
        // init array to all Zeroes
        grid = Array(repeating: 0, count: bufLength)
        
        var row1: Int = 2
        var row2: Int = gridHeight - (row1 + 1)
        var col1: Int = gridWidth / 2 - 1
        var col2: Int = col1 + 1
        for r in row1...row2 {
            for c in col1...col2 {
                let p = r * gridWidth + c
                grid[p] = 1
            }
        }
        row1 = gridHeight / 2 - 1
        row2 = row1 + 1
        col1 = 2
        col2 = gridWidth - (col1 + 1)
        for r in row1...row2 {
            for c in col1...col2 {
                let p = r * gridWidth + c
                grid[p] = 1
            }
        }
        
        refreshGrid(grid)
        
    }
    
    @objc func setupTriangle() {
        
        // init array to all Zeroes
        grid = Array(repeating: 0, count: bufLength)
        
        var row: Int = 1
        
        var col1: Int = gridWidth / 2 - 1
        var col2: Int = col1 + 1
        
        let p: Int = row * gridWidth + col1
        grid[p] = 1
        grid[p + 1] = 1
        row += 1
        col1 -= 1
        col2 += 1
        
        while col1 > 0 {
            var p1: Int = row * gridWidth + col1
            var p2: Int = row * gridWidth + col2
            grid[p1] = 1
            grid[p2] = 1
            row += 1
            
            p1 = row * gridWidth + col1
            p2 = row * gridWidth + col2
            grid[p1] = 1
            grid[p2] = 1
            row += 1
            
            col1 -= 1
            col2 += 1
        }
        for c in col1...col2 {
            let p: Int = row * gridWidth + c
            grid[p] = 1
        }
        
        refreshGrid(grid)
        
    }
    
    @objc func setupRandom() {
        
        // init array to all Zeroes
        grid = Array(repeating: 0, count: bufLength)
        
        // we'll fill grid with random excluding
        //  the first color, to make it easier to see
        //  the changes
        for r in 0..<gridHeight {
            for c in 0..<gridWidth {
                let p = r * gridWidth + c
                grid[p] = Int.random(in: 1..<colors.count)
            }
        }
        
        let idx: Int = 0
        
        for i in 0..<colorStack.arrangedSubviews.count {
            colorStack.arrangedSubviews[i].layer.borderWidth = i == idx ? 1 : 0
        }
        
        newColor = idx
        
        refreshGrid(grid)
        
    }
    
}
```

It looks like this when running:

[image]

Tapping a color-box at the top will select the "replacement color".

Tapping a box inside the grid will perform the Flood Fill.

Since this would ideally be used directly on a buffer of image data, the "Elapsed Time" value is for the **Int Array process only** -- it does not include refreshing the UI (the grid of colors/numbers).

Tapping on the labeled buttons sets up an initial pattern:

[image]

[image]

Use Random and then select various contiguous squares to try out a winding path:

[image]

Comment: In addition to this if we return only updated coloured pixel position then it will further reduce the time

Comment: @Nick - not really... first, assuming you'd eventually be using this algorithm on an image, you'd be modifying the image data itself, not passing an array and returning a new array. In this sample code, we could either use an `inout` parameter and pass `&grid`, then modify it directly and return true or false if it was modified... or, since `grid` is a class-level property, we could *not* pass it and just have the code modify the `grid` array itself. This is pretty fast as-is though.

Comment: @DoneMag agreed! But you know what on 256 grid its delaying the color filling. I am using single pixel as CALayer. Not sure though. The algorithm is fast but setting colour is taking around 3 sec (256 X 256 grid)

Comment: @Nick - are you saying you're adding 65,536 sublayers to a view?

Comment: @DoneMag Yes, CALayers are light compare to view

Comment: @Nick - the example code I provided was just an interface to test the algorithm. Adding and manipulating 65,536 sublayers sounds crazy, and I'm surprised UIKit allows that many to begin with. You need to explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I thought so, in mean while I am also exploring an option with SpriteKit

Comment: @Nick - this is why I said *"you need to explain what you're really trying to do."*

Comment: Hey @DonMag, I am building pixel-art like application

Comment: @Nick - well, great, but that still doesn't explain **exactly** what you're trying to do with this specific task. Are you trying to manipulate **image data**? Are you trying to set colors of a grid of rectangles? Are you trying to set individual pixels (or points?) of a `UIView`? My guess is that you should be overriding `draw()`. Since this answer resolved your problem with the flood-fill algorithm, you may want to post a new question detailing what you're trying to do next and where you're having trouble.